# SingleCellExperiment: invalid rownames length

Tags: r

I did all of the installations from scratch in a virtual `conda` environment. Then I tried to run `R` script from within `javascript` in the following way:

```
let shCMD = 'Rscript --vanilla R/full_analysis.R ';
  shCMD += '--diff_1 ' + diff_str_1 + '--diff_2 ' + diff_str_2;
  shCMD += '--markers ' + filterStr + '--markers-highlighted ' + colorStr;
  shCMD += '--datasets ' + datasetStr;

  console.log('constructed command for full analysis: ');
  console.log(shCMD);
  shell.exec('source activate rmain', function(env_code, env_stdout, 
env_stderr) {
    console.log('activated rmain environment')
    if (env_code === 0) {
      shell.exec(shCMD, function(code, stdout, stderr) {
```

As can be seen I am activating the environment by `source activate rmain` and I am pretty sure that the next shell command that invokes `R` script runs in that environment because `R` script needs `argparse` package and it is installed only in the `rmain` virtual environment: in `rmain` `argparse` package is successfully imported, but outside of it it gives an error for the `argparse` absence.

So, now the following line in the `R` script:

```
sce <- SingleCellExperiment(list(counts=as.matrix(data[,-1])))
```

gives me the error:

```
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("0610007P14Rik", "0610009B22Rik",  : 
  invalid rownames length
Calls: SingleCellExperiment ... elementMetadata -> .local -> rownames<- -> rownames<-
Execution halted
```

However, if I launch `Rstudio` from within the `rmain` environment, the line runs successfully... So, I am puzzled now on what is going on.

Comment: If it works interactively (in Rstudio) but not as a script it could be because R loads certain libraries for you in an interactive session. You could try adding `library(methods)` to the script and see if you still have the same problem